# What is the point of defining a constructor type as an object property?

Tags: typescript

I know, that I can define types for classes in TypeScript by typing the constructor of the class. Here's an example of a factory function I took from the TypeScript Documentation ([Using Class Types in Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#using-class-types-in-generics)):

> When creating factories in TypeScript using generics, it is necessary to refer to class types by their constructor...
>
> ```
> function create<Type>(c: { new (): Type }): Type {
>   return new c();
> }
> ```

However, I've seen many people doing this in a slightly different way:

```
function create<Type>(c: new () => Type): Type {
  return new c();
}
```

As you can see, the parameter `c` now has the type `new () => Type` instead of `{ new (): Type }`. So I was wondering what exactly the difference is between these two variants. They appear to work pretty much the same considering that the compiler seems to infer both approaches identically.

```
type Class<Type> = new (...args: any[]) => Type;
type Class2<Type> = {new (...args: any[]): Type};
//   ^? type Class2<Type> = new (...args: any[]) => Type
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgNgQwM5IDwBVwQHxQLxQB2EA7lABQB01CATgOZIBcUChIA2gLoCU%20umSAG4AsAChQkWIhQAmDFlwEA3sTJUaDZq3bceLQRAC%20osQHozUKwD0A-OPEBjGUijoISYFGVGHYgGYAroSOwACWAPaEUI60EAjAEAqQ2OSOLPDIaIbY%20m5Y3uJWccCBtNFqMeQ8pr5i4kEh4VExcQkQ8jlpGS6dinmGhWLFEKXlRKRVNeJ1Tm2J5O6e02Kx8Ymyix7ANUA)

Comment: The difference lies in how the type annotations are written, and the choice often comes down to personal preference.